# odd button element behavior requiring type attribute vs input element in firefox 38.05

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, firefox

I have an .NET/aspx page with an embedded  element:

...

I use jquery to bind a click event to it

$('body').delegate('#btnSave', 'click', onSaveClick);

This works perfectly well in my Chrome and IE browsers, however, in Firefox (at least 38.05), the click does not fire the onSaveClick event (the page seems to get refreshed, but it never reaches the onSaveClick handler). Oddly enough, if I change the button element to:

...

Now it works in Firefox. Of course I am just adding the type in for now, but I'd love to know if anyone can explain why this seemingly redundant info is needed.

Thanks for any clues!

-jonathan

Comment: Sounds like a form submit - FF uses a button like a submit button, so you'll have a click event and the submit event. Try to add preventDefault() to the event param of your clickHandler.

Comment: thanks axel I think you solved it, when I added preventDefault() in my click handler that also worked, and that looks better than my workaround -- which I see was removed in my post, I added a type="button" attribute to the button element.